# Why cant i get data from this request and from this address "https://twin-mess-app.glitch.me/login"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

```
var address1 = "https://twin-mess-app.glitch.me/login";
var address2 = "https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent";
$.getJSON(address1 , function (data) {
  jArray = data; 
  console.log(jArray);
});
```

I can log data from address2 in console but i can't log data form address1. Why? How to fix it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: how to make address1 work with console.log(jArray); ?

Answer (score 0):

The CORS header allows cross origin request on address2 but address1's server does not have this header set.

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I don't understand. How can i get data from address1 and log it in the console.